# How to know system requirement of an app?

Tags: hardware-requirements

I am developing an Android app for my homework.
And now I am confused to write the hardware requirements of my app.

Example:

- How much GHertz of CPU
- How much RAM, etc.

Comment: Just write the lowest spec possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're creating a regular app, like a feed, news or a browser, there's no need to specify a hardware (performance) requirement as such apps usually run fluently on a mediocre device.

If it's a game, the best would be buying a variety of devices with different specs and test them one-by-one, and decide the minimum requirement for the game to run fluently. Im case it's too expensive/unnecessary, you can run it on a device that you own, then compare its performance with a benchmark app like 3DMark or GFXBench. Look for benchmarks for other chips, and estimate the minimum requirement according to your game's test result and the benchmark results on different chips.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions (guess you again confused this with SO?)

Comment: @Izzy This question is surely salvageable if words related to development is edited out, though I'm not motivated to do so.

Comment: @Izzy Had the OP posted a block of code I wouldn't have answered this.

Comment: "if words related to development is edited out" it would be a completely different question :)

Comment: Confusing thing is that you marked it OT and still answered it :) And I'm not sure if such an edit would be a good idea here, so I rather refrain from advice.

Comment: i am sorry,  i don't know where to ask, anyway thanks, i will looking for other place .